# How to make two tables with naming of the rows at the side?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to make two tables side by side. I think it's best to show you what I am trying to achieve with an example:

[image] [image]

Both of the tables should be of the style of the right table. In the picture I drew the left table should be exactly the same as shown in the right image. The right table in the picture I drew only have 2 entries at the top. But besides that it is still the same style.

I tried to achieve a table like in the right image with the following:

```
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll|ll}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Nächstes Nukleotid} \\ \hline
 & & A & T & C & G \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{4em}{Vorheriges Nukleotid} &  A & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
& T & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
& C & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
& G & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{tabular}
\caption{Übersetzung Regel 888}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But that only produces the following:

[image]

And thats not looking good in my opinion. So how can I achieve something like in the right image demonstrated?

Comment: A `table` environment is allowed to have anything.  In this case, have you tried having two `tabular` environments?

Comment: @Teepeemm Are you suggesting that I should try to make like an outer table with the "real" table (with the As, etc.) inside of it?

Comment: I see no "As, etc.".  You currently have `\begin{table} \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \end{table}`.  It is perfectly fine to have `\begin{table} \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \quad \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} \end{table}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it's better to typeset adjacent tables as one single table with twice as many columns. That way if the entries have different heights you still get good horizontal alignment.

Here is an possibility with `nicematrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{r|cccccr|ccccc}
\Block{2-2}{}&& \Block{1-4}{Vorheriges Nukleotid} &&&&\Block{2-2}{}&& \Block{1-4}{Binärziffern} &&& \\ \cline{3-6}\cline{9-12}
&& A & T & C & G &&& \Block{1-2}{0} && \Block{1-2}{1}\\ 
\Block{4-1}{Nächstes\\Nukleotid} & A & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \Block{4-1}{\qquad Vorheriges\\Nukleotid} & A & A & G & C & G \\
 & T & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & & T & C & T & A & G \\
 & C & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & & G & A & G & C & T \\
 & G & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & & C & C & T & A & G
\CodeAfter
    \SubMatrix.{3-3}{6-6}.[hvlines, xshift=5.5pt]
    \tikz \draw ([shift={(.4pt,.4pt)}]7-|3)rectangle([yshift=.4pt]3-|7);
    \SubMatrix.{3-9}{6-12}.[hvlines, xshift=5.5pt]
    \tikz \draw ([shift={(.4pt,.4pt)}]7-|9)rectangle([yshift=.4pt]3-|13);
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem like the following:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{tabular}{llllll}
                                                &                        & \multicolumn{4}{l}{nächstes Nukleotid}           \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                &                        &   &                        &   &   \\
                                                &                        & A & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T} & C & G \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                &                        &   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}  &   &   \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{v. N.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{A} & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & 1 & 0 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T} & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & 0 & 1 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{C} & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0} & 0 & 1 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{G} & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{1} & 1 & 0
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}{llllll}
                                                &                        & \multicolumn{4}{l}{Binärziffer}                           \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                &                        &   &                        &           &           \\
                                                &                        & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0}     & \multicolumn{2}{l}{1} \\ \cline{3-6} 
                                                &                        &   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}  &           &           \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{v. N.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{A} & A & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{G} & C         & T         \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T} & C & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T} & A         & G         \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{C} & C & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{T} & A         & G         \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{G} & A & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{G} & C         & T        
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: Excellent.  BTW, `\begin{table}[h!]` is not the best, because it doesn't give LaTeX many options on where to place your tables.  It's best to drop the `[h!]` and let LaTeX put your tables where it thinks is best (and adjust your exposition accordingly).  If you *must* put your table *here*, and don't need a caption, you can just use `\begin{center}` instead of `\begin{table}`.  If you really need a caption, you can look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/107497.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to adjust my text then :-)